# changing div height on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want is a div at the top (header) that will be at maximum height (50px) when you first load the page, and when you're scrolling down the page I want the height to smoothly decrease to a minimun height of 30px. I'm guessing I should use jQuery for this but I'm not that experienced so I don't know a solution at the moment.

Here's my current, undeveloped HTML and CSS:

[HTML]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header_parent">

        </div>

        <!-- Body (homepage) -->
        <div id="body_parent">

        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer_parent">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[CSS]

```
* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#header_parent {
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    height:50px;
}
```

So to be clear, the `#header_parent` element is what I'm talking about.

I also found a website on which they achieved this matter: [tvgids.tv](http://tvgids.tv)
(don't look at the content, it's they upper grey header I'm talking about. I tried looking at the source code but that didn't give me any more knowledge.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've added to #body_parent height to see the scroll, you can delete that row with height after you create the site.

Here is jsfiddle

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
        $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "30px"},200);
    }
    else {
         $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "50px"},200);   
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#header_parent {
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
}

#body_parent {
     height:1200px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header_parent">
        
    </div>
    
    <!-- Body (homepage) -->
    <div id="body_parent">
        
    </div>
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer_parent">
        
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Or HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header_parent">

        </div>

        <!-- Body (homepage) -->
        <div id="body_parent">

        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer_parent">

        </div>

     <!-- jQuery library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Your jQuery/Javascript code -->
     <script  type="text/javascript">
     $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 50) {
            $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "30px"},200);
        }
        else {
             $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "50px"},200);   
        }
     });
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you want to set smoothness replace 200 with your number, 200 mean duration in miliseconds.

```
$('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "50px"},200);
```

Comment: Looks great already, but it's not exactly the way I meant it to be. I want the height to change dynamically with the scroll wheel.
However, this is a great solution for now, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without jQuery.

```
var header = document.getElementById("header_parent");

window.onscroll = function(e) {
    if(window.scrollY) {
        if(window.pageYOffset > 50) {
            header.style.height = 30;
        } else {
            header.style.height = 50;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also toggle class names inside the `if` block instead of setting the height explicitly.

Comment: Add it in a <script></script> tag before the closing of the <head> tag. You can also link to a separate <script> file. Just google 'where do i add javascript'.