# Img resize on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i resize a logo( es width: 100px ) in a header on mouse scrolling?

```js
$('.logo').scroll(function() {
    $(this).width(100);
    $(this).off(); //removes the handler so that it only resizes once...
})
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://unika.myarmah.it/skin/frontend/sns_simo/default/images/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
<div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look here - [changing div height on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676253/changing-div-height-on-scroll) can be used for width accordingly

Answer (score 1):

*Just use javascript*:

Why? - Because its just as short as using jQuery.

#### Update #1 -

after seeing the comments to the previous answer from the author, I have adjusted my example to include animation and reset when at the top of the page. Again - just use javascript, and for better performance benefits use CSS classes so that all paints are done in one cycle.

Update #1 jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/113dn29z/16/

```
var logo = document.querySelector('.logo');

var handleResize = function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop === 0) {
       logo.classList.remove("resize");
    } else {
       logo.classList.add("resize");
    }
};

document.addEventListener('scroll', handleResize);
```

---

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo">
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
  height: 9999px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.header {
  background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.logo.resize {
  width: 100px;
}
```

---

*old jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/113dn29z/10/*

Answer (score 0):

```
var logoHasResized = false;
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    if (window.scrollY == 0) {
        $('.logo').animate({'width': '100%'}, 250);
        logoHasResized = false;
    } else if (logoHasResized == false) {
        $('.logo').animate({'width': 100}, 250);
        logoHasResized = true;
    }
});
```

edit: Since you want it to go back when you scroll to the top of the page, i've added in a check to see if the animation has happened, as you don't want it to fire constantly.

Comment: if I want to add an animation?

Comment: @yavonz15, i edited the response for it to be animated.

Comment: fanastic, how return to the original size when i return top page?